# Odd behavior with 2d array indexing

Tags: c++, matrix, multidimensional-array

So I have this matrix class and I added a constructor that takes in an "array" (it uses an initializer list) to form a matrix.

So this array,

```cpp
{
    2, 3, 3, 4,
    5, 6, 7, 9,
    2, 2, 5, 7,
    3, 4, 6, 3
}
```

would create this matrix.

```cpp
[2 3 3 4]
[5 6 7 9]
[2 2 5 7]
[3 4 6 3]
```

And after playing around for around 40 minutes I was able to come up with this code. (by complete accident)

```cpp
Matrix(initializer_list<float> constructor) {
    int row = 0, column = 0;
    for (float v : constructor) {
        matrix[row][column++] = v;
    }
}
```

How did this give me the result I was looking for?

What I was trying to do in the process was do something like this.

```cpp
// "If the column is greater than 3, move to the next row and reset the column"
matrix[(column > 3 ? ++row, column = 0 : row)][column++] = v;
```

Comment: Use a debugger and more variables and you will get that the expression `(column > 3 ? ++row, column = 0 : row` does not return a value that you expect if column reaches 3.

Comment: Please make a [mre], in particular show the declaration of  `matrix`.

Comment: We need to see the declaration of `matrix`

Comment: The Matrix when using the constructor looks like this.

Matrix({
    0, 3, 2, 1,
    // ...
});

The Matrix array in the class is defined as a 2d array.
float matrix[4][4] = {0.0f};

Comment: Please add all information to the question, not as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'm not sure what class `initializer list` is. I'm going to assume it's a similar structure to std::array for the purposes of explanation, but take this with a grain of salt if it's not so. Secondly, I'm going to assume that `matrix` in your constructor code is a 2D array of size 4, with 4 sub arrays of size 4, that is defined in the matrix class.

Breaking down the code we get these steps:

1. The list is passed to the Matrix constructor
2. Two integers are defined, `row` and `column` each initialized to 0
3. A for loop iterates over the provided list, starting from the value 2 at index 0, moving one at a time until it reaches the value 3 at index 15. Every iteration of the loop assigns the current value to the variable v, then places it at the specified row and column

Now I think any confusion you have in this code may step from your use of the `++` operator. The way you've done it in your code is actually undefined, as the C++ standard does not specify what should happen when ++ is used inside of an evaluated expression where it's result matters. If you're using MSVC, usually what happens is the number actually used as your index is the original value for column, then column is increased by 1. This means for your first iteration of the loop the value used in the assignment in place of `column++` is 0, then it's 1, then 2... all the way to 15.

Now does this code actually do what you want it to do? No. It definitely, absolutely, does not. The value for `row` is 0 the entire time, and is never changed. Essentially what this code has done is copy the original array to the array matrix[0]. What would be a better option in my opinion is to forgo the idea of checking when to reset the column and just make 2 nested for loops to store the column and row numbers. Or, even better, just use `memcpy` to copy the array into your `matrix` array, and don't worry about making a 2D array at all. It's better on memory and efficiency.

Comment: The [`initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) template has been in the language since C++11.

Comment: @molbdnilo oh, thank you for telling me. I didn't know that was a C++ class.